# Nginx certbot Failed https connexion

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am trying to connect with https request. 
It's really weird because it works when iam trying to connect when :

`/opt/certbot/certbot-auto --dry-run renew`

is running I can access my websites on Mozilla Firefox .

But a son as the `--dry-run renew` end with no errors of courses I can't..
Any idea ?

I did not link my nginx conf file because like I said i can acces while cert-bot is challenging the websites.

Mozzila return a "Secure Connection Failed"